Identify valid points on a map
I have a binary matrix that I turned into a maze map for my project
I have a code that I wrote down that goes through a lot of points
I want to know if each of the points falls on an allowed area (white area) or a prohibited area (black or red area)
I can't seem to build a function that really does this thoroughly. Everything I've tried captures in terms of accuracy only on some of the points
I would appreciate assistance with the code, thanks a lot
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import binary_dilation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the scaled matrix (50x50)
scaled_matrix = np.loadtxt("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\bgeProjects\\scaled_matrix.txt", delimiter='\t')

# Inflate obstacles in the occupancy grid using binary dilation
structuring_element = np.ones((3, 3))
inflated_matrix = binary_dilation(scaled_matrix, structure=structuring_element).astype(scaled_matrix.dtype)

# Extract all free positions (positions with 0 in the inflated matrix)
free_positions = np.argwhere(inflated_matrix == 0)
free_positions = [tuple(pos) for pos in free_positions]

# Detect horizontal and vertical edges
horizontal_edges = np.diff(inflated_matrix, axis=1)
vertical_edges = np.diff(inflated_matrix, axis=0)

# Plot the map and the free positions
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
cmap = plt.cm.colors.ListedColormap(['white', 'black'])

height, width = inflated_matrix.shape
flipped_matrix = np.flipud(inflated_matrix)

plt.imshow(flipped_matrix, cmap=cmap, origin='lower', extent=[0, width, 0, height])
plt.scatter(3, 3, color='red', marker='o', s=10, label='Check Point')

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width - 1):
        if horizontal_edges[y, x] != 0:
            plt.plot([x + 1, x + 1], [height - y, height - (y + 1)], color='red')

for y in range(height - 1):
    for x in range(width):
        if vertical_edges[y, x] != 0:
            plt.plot([x, x + 1], [height - (y + 1), height - (y + 1)], color='red')

plt.xticks(np.arange(0, width + 1, 1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, height + 1, 1))

plt.title('Inflated Map with Free Positions and Boundaries')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()

def is_in_white_area(x, y):
    if 0 <= x < width and 0 <= y < height:
        # Get integer floor and ceil values for coordinates
        x_floor, x_ceil = int(np.floor(x)), int(np.ceil(x))
        y_floor, y_ceil = int(np.floor(y)), int(np.ceil(y))

        # Check if the point is on the edge by examining adjacent cells
        edge_check = (x_floor < width - 1 and horizontal_edges[height - y_floor - 1, x_floor] != 0) or \
                     (y_floor < height - 1 and vertical_edges[height - y_floor - 1, x_floor] != 0) or \
                     (x_ceil < width - 1 and horizontal_edges[height - y_ceil - 1, x_ceil] != 0) or \
                     (y_ceil < height - 1 and vertical_edges[height - y_ceil - 1, x_ceil] != 0)
        
        if edge_check:
            return False  # Point is on the red edge line

        # Interpolate to determine the value at the decimal coordinates
        q11 = inflated_matrix[height - y_floor - 1, x_floor]
        q12 = inflated_matrix[height - y_ceil - 1, x_floor]
        q21 = inflated_matrix[height - y_floor - 1, x_ceil]
        q22 = inflated_matrix[height - y_ceil - 1, x_ceil]

        x_ratio = x - x_floor
        y_ratio = y - y_floor

        top_interp = q11 * (1 - x_ratio) + q21 * x_ratio
        bottom_interp = q12 * (1 - x_ratio) + q22 * x_ratio
        value = top_interp * (1 - y_ratio) + bottom_interp * y_ratio

        return value == 0  # True if in white area, False otherwise
    else:
        return False  # Out of bounds

# Example usage with decimal coordinates:
x_coord = 25
y_coord = 42.1324325
valid_pos = is_in_white_area(x_coord, y_coord)
print(valid_pos)  # Should return True or False based on your plot
plt.scatter(x_coord, y_coord, color='green', marker='x', s=100, label='Check Point')
plt.show()


this is my matrix:
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

The example below shows how to use matplotlib.path.Path to find the grid points located within a path. If you can define the white area as a list of coordinates, this might work. Higher resolution can be attained by reducing the grid spacing.

Reproducible example
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Define and plot contour
contour_points = np.array([
    (0.1, 0.3), (4.4, 1.4,), (6.2, 5.8), (7.3, 8.6), (4.5, 7.5), (1.3, 2.3),
])

contour_points = np.array([ 
    [0.6, 5.5], 
    [2.8, 5.3], 
    [2.1, 8.2], 
    [5.3, 8.8], 
    [5, 2.1], 
    [8.4, 2.4], 
    [8.3, 5.3], 
    [10, 5.4], 
    [10.3, 0], 
    [0.5, 2] 
]) + [0.5, -0.5]

plt.plot(
    contour_points[:, 0], contour_points[:, 1],
    color='dodgerblue', marker='o', label='contour points'
)

#Define and plot grid
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10), np.arange(10))
xy_grid_points = np.column_stack([x_grid.ravel(), y_grid.ravel()])

plt.scatter(
    xy_grid_points[:, 0], xy_grid_points[:, 1],
    marker='.', color='crimson', label='grid points'
)

#Convert contour to Path object, and view filled path
from matplotlib.path import Path
contour_path = Path(contour_points)

#Just for visualisation, shade path as a patch
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
plt.gca().add_patch(
    PathPatch(contour_path, alpha=0.1, color='dodgerblue', hatch='////', label='path patch')
)
# plt.fill(
#     contour_points[:, 0], contour_points[:, 1],
#     alpha=0.1, color='dodgerblue', hatch='////', label='path patch'
# )

#Identify and highlight grid points within the path
within_path_bool = contour_path.contains_points(xy_grid_points)
points_inside_path = xy_grid_points[within_path_bool, :]

plt.scatter(
    points_inside_path[:, 0], points_inside_path[:, 1],
    marker='s', color='lightgray', s=70, zorder=0, label='within path'
)

plt.legend(framealpha=1, shadow=True, fancybox=True, loc='upper right')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.gca().spines[:].set_visible(False)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(7, 4)

